# Count() Keeps Zeroing Out

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to do a count statement do show how many specific versions each category has. The problem is, whenever a version is over one, the result zeros out.

For example, if there are three of one category with two of them having one version while the other having another version, the count of the version with two instances will show '0' instead of '2'in the results. When the category has just one of each version, it works perfect. It's only when there is more than one instance of a version that it 0s out.

Does anyone know how to fix? I'm assuming it's in my case statements, but I'm not certain.

My code is below.

```
select Category, Count(Case When Version = 'Offer' then 1 end) as Offers, Count(Case When Version = 'No Offer' then 1 end) as [No Offers] from (
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By Category order by version) as GroupOrder, DENSE_RANK() over (order by category) as GroupNo From Input 
) A
where groupno in 
(
select groupno from (
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By Category order by version) as GroupOrder, DENSE_RANK() over (order by category) as GroupNo From Input 
) A where GroupOrder > 1) and ID not in 
(
select ID from
(
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By Category, Version order by version) as GroupOrder, DENSE_RANK() over (order by category, Version) as GroupNo From Input 
) A
where groupno in 
(
select groupno from 
(
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By Category, Version order by version) as GroupOrder, DENSE_RANK() over (order by category, Version) as GroupNo From Input 
) A where GroupOrder > 1) 
)
group by Category
order by  Category
```

Comment: if you're just counting 1's you can change it to SUM and see if you get same result.. `SUM(CASE WHEN Version = 'Offer' THEN 1 END) AS Offers` version in a reserved word also so you may want to use brackets around it like [Version]

Comment: Using SUM yields the same result, unfortunately

Comment: I've appeared to have found the cause of the issue. Whenever a category returns multiple instances of a version, it gets removed from the results generated by the query. It works fine if each category has just one of each version, but it doesn't show when there is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of success using `CTE's` for this type of problem.  This may give you the answer you are looking for.

```
;WITH CTE
  AS (SELECT Category,
             CASE WHEN [Version] = 'Offer' THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
               END AS Offers,
             CASE WHEN [Version] = 'No Offer' THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END AS [No Offers]
        FROM
          (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY version) AS GroupOrder
                   , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY category) AS GroupNo
            FROM Input) A
        WHERE GroupNo IN
          (SELECT GroupNo
             FROM (SELECT *
                        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY version) AS GroupOrder
                        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY category) AS GroupNo
                    FROM   Input) A
             WHERE   GroupOrder > 1)
               AND ID NOT IN
                 (SELECT ID
                   FROM
                     (SELECT *
                           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category, Version ORDER BY version) AS GroupOrder
                           , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY category, Version) AS GroupNo
                       FROM   Input) A
                   WHERE GroupNo IN
                     (SELECT GroupNo
                       FROM 
                         (SELECT *
                               , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category, Version ORDER BY version) AS GroupOrder
                               , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY category, Version) AS GroupNo
                           FROM Input) A
                       WHERE   GroupOrder > 1)))
  SELECT Category,
         SUM(Offers) AS Offers,
         SUM([No Offers]) AS Offers
    FROM [CTE]
    GROUP BY Category
    ORDER BY Category
```

Comment: It's still resulting in zeroes whenever an instance greater than one occurs. I'm just at a blank as to why